# Apache CXF and servlet-mapping

Tags: servlets, cxf

I am trying to learn some basics of Apache CXF and generally about servlet-mappings.
and I have modified the code here:

https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/pablo-examples/spring-cxf-example

I have configured CXFServlet mapping as below in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in the spring xml(webservice-definition-beans.xml) 
I have generated the service as below

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld" implementor="#helloWorldService" address="/services/HelloWorld" />
```

I was expecting to access to the service wsdl via this url

```
http://localhost:8080/services/HelloWorld?wsdl
```

but it is

```
http://localhost:8080/services/services/HelloWorld?wsdl
```

Do I know something wrong here ?

Does not servlet-mapping only show which url pattern maps to which servlet to process ?

In here It seems it also changes context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JAX-WS path is relative to servlet mapping.  If you want

```
http://localhost:8080/services/HelloWorld?wsdl
```

use either

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld" implementor="#helloWorldService" address="/services/HelloWorld" />
```

or

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld" implementor="#helloWorldService" address="/HelloWorld" />
```