# Adding URL Excemption for Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I'm new to Keycloak so I apologize if this is an easy question.

I have to have my entire website hidden behind Keycloak, except for one or two urls.  These endpoints are necessary for our rest server, so stuff like "/rest/service/status" should not be challenged.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know either of an easy way doing this. But may it helps you that if your are securing your service via servlet it is possible to define `url-pattern`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977730/apache-cxf-and-servlet-mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add security exemption for the URL  using web.xml or spring-security.xml  like

```
<security:http pattern = "/YOUR_URL/**" security = "none"/>
```